# Using parameters for JMH benchmark methods

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I've written two methods whose performances I need to compare. Both methods take in parameters, so I've made two separate fields with the @Param annotation - one for each of the methods. The parameters are used independently (AKA each method only uses its respective field and don't make use of the @Param field that the other method uses). I've read that JMH runs tests using the permutations of the @Param fields, but I don't need EVERY permutation tested since each method just uses its own parameter. For each method, is there a way to have JMH run tests to measure performance while only cycling through the @Param field it uses?

What I'm doing right now is that I've separated the two @Param fields into two distinct State classes, and I have each method take in the corresponding state object as a parameter. This seems unnecessary to me though, since the only difference between the two State classes is the @Param field (the rest of the setup, etc. is the same for both classes). Is there a more concise way to go about this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should split the question in two as these are two different questions. First one is understandable and has a good solution, the second one needs clarification (first of all, what is the expected outcome of running different interations with different parameters).

Comment: I ended up just removing the second question as it turns out it's not important - I'll post it as a second question if necessary. Thanks